# Bid/Ask volumes on stock markets

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, bid-ask

I recently got into buying some low volume stocks (mostly at NYSE) and noticed that sometimes when I buy/sell I get slightly different execution cost then when I hit the sell/buy button. I've figured that this might be because of low volume of stock available given the shown cost.

**Is it possible to see how much volume is available at each price for Bid/Ask, for example [like this](https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/WfXKoXluvUC3Ychrne76C8Jmxmw=/1364x650/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/buysellorder-5c60e416c9e77c0001662248.JPG) on Steam Market? This data must be seen by the exchange so they should be available somewhere right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent broker will provide a size quote (volume) along with the NBBO price quote as seen in your link.  However, there may be additional shares available if there are hidden orders at those prices (a hidden order masks the true size of an order).

Getting a different fill price depends on several things.  The most obvious is that if you're placing a market order whose size is greater than available volume, you'll be filled at different prices.

If you place an AON limit price whose size is modestly greater than the available volume at your price, sometimes the counterparty will give you those shares as well as a modest amount at a slightly better price for the sake of completing their side of the trade.

Also, maker/taker fees can affect the fill price modestly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went and tried to search in the options and found it under "Market Depth" in "Settings" in my XTB broker account. At least for crypto, it works now. I can see how much for which price is possible. Also I found out that if I buy through dialog window instead of directly from graph view, it will automatically recalculate the price for me depending on the volume, so that is good to know as well. To see if the stocks are the same, I must check when the market is open.

Comment: So I checked and I don't see market depth for stocks at NYSE so I wonder if it because of my broker does not provide them or if its some policy of the exchange?

Comment: Any decent broker will provide Level 1 quotes (best bid-offer along with the respective volume). Level 2 displays  order book and market depth information and that's often a subscription service.